# I want to exclude some class from html use jquery, for exmple $('html').not('.classname'), but it did not work?

Tags: jquery

I want to exclude some class use jquery, for exmple $('html').not('.classname'), but it did not work? what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current syntax is trying to select a `html` tag that doesn't have the given class.

You probably won't have a class on your `html` tag.

What you want might be

```
$('*:not(.className)')
```

This selects all the elements except the one's with that given class.

Alternatively you could use

```
$("*").not(".className")
```

which would not be recommendable performance-wise, since it would select all elements first, only then removing the ones not having that `.className`.

This selects all the elements (including head, body etc) except the one's with that given class.

This is not a efficient way to select elements.

It  will be better if you be more specific in your selection like select all `div` elements with out this className.

`$('div:not(.className)')`

Or more specifically within a main div

`$('#mainDivId div:not(.className)')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to bind a click event on all html exclude some class,  how to do it?

Comment: This is likely what you're looking for but I would take a step back and think more about your strategy here @Superman -- it seems there must be some other way of approaching your problem.

Comment: Just add .click() with your callback

Comment: @RobbieAverill, I try $('*:not(.className)')   and $("*").not(".className") , both did not work ,  still did not exclude some classname, could you help me ?

Comment: @Superman then this is not the approach for your problem.. You can just have `$(html).on('click',someFunction)` and within this `someFunction` you will just have to check if the clicked element has the specific class, if so do nothing else run your scripts. Hope you get the idea